# TCPDF multiple custom header function

Tags: php, header, tcpdf

I have 2 bottoms one to generate custom header in landscape and other bottom to generate other custom header in portrait,  IF I made `public function Header(){}` its working fine but how can make 2 header function to tell the `new MYPDF` and `SetHeaderData` which header should be use ? thank you.

Comment: You don't make two separate methods inside the same class. What you do is this: you implement two classes, both derived from the same tcpdf class. In each class you implement one of the header functions you want to implement. That way you can simply decide which header you want in the document by choosing one of the classes and instantiate an object of that class (example: `new myPdfClassWithHeaderOne`).

Comment: good idea @arkascha going to do a test.

Comment: working good ... really thank you!!